# How can I commit only specific files in Git?

Tags: git, github

If there are 1000 files in my local repository, and I want to commit and push only 700 files, is there a possibility?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+commit+some+files

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git commit [files]` in order to commit only certain files to your repository OR you can make use of Git's staging area to gradually add the files you want using `git add [file]` before you commit.

You can check out [this guide](https://dev.to/sublimegeek/git-staging-area-explained-like-im-five-1anh) for a more complete introduction to Git and version control.